# Clean uninstall of Adobe Air application?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uninstall, adobe-air, vimeo

How can I do a clean reinstall of this Adobe Air application?

How do I remove the local data stored by this Adobe Air application?

I installed the Vimeo desktop uploader, an Adobe Air application, on my Ubuntu Linux system.

I dragged too many videos into the window, and the program was taking a while and the window grayed, as if it were temporarily blocked because it was processing.
I killed the program. When I reloaded it, the window grayed again, as if it resumed processing where it left off.

I killed the program and tried to remove the local data:

```
rm  -Rf ~/.appdata/vimeo.Duplo.3E2F2984357E7A95AE95C69EF2C5C14640284048.1/
```

but the window was still grayed and unresponsive when I reloaded the program.

I tried to uninstall the program:

```
sudo dpkg -P vimeo.duplo.3e2f2984357e7a95ae95c69ef2c5c14640284048.1
```

and then reinstall it and then run it. But when I ran the reinstalled program, instead of prompting me to give my personal login information, the window was still grayed and unresponsive as if it remembered my login information and skipped the first step.

How can I do a clean reinstall of this Adobe Air application?

How do I remove the local data stored by this Adobe Air application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, there was also the encrypted data to remove:

```
 rm -Rf ~/.appdata/Adobe/AIR/ELS/vimeo.Duplo.3E2F2984357E7A95AE95C69EF2C5C14640284048.1/
```

See this article on the [ELS](http://pixelbits.wordpress.com/2008/07/26/adobe-air-deleting-locally-stored-encrypted-data-without-visiting-the-genius-bar/)